# Numpy choice based on another array

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I want to select some elements from an array `main_array` if the indexes correspond indexes with a `True` value in another array. For example `y` should contain `[14,15,16]` in arbitrary order

```
import numpy as np

main_array = np.array([11,12,13,14,15,16])
selector = np.array([0,1,2,3,3,3])
x = np.random.choice(main_array, 3, replace=False)  # This works
y = np.random.choice(main_array, 3, replace=False, p=np.where(selector>2)) # This fails
```

However, I get `ValueError: 'p' must be 1-dimensional`
What is the correct way to limit selection to indexes based on another array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A way to do it is just make by parts:

```py
import numpy as np

main_array = np.array([11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16])
selector = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3])
x = np.random.choice(main_array, 3, replace=False)
z = main_array[selector > 2]
y = np.random.choice(z, len(z), replace=False)
print(f"x={x}")
print(f"z={z}")
print(f"y={y}")
```

The output is

```
x=[16 14 13]
z=[14 15 16]
y=[16 15 14]
```

Another way to make it is to put the probabilities equal to zero where the `mask` doesn't apply:

```py
import numpy as np

main_array = np.array([11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16])
selector = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3])
x = np.random.choice(main_array, 3, replace=False)

p = 1 * (selector > 2)
y = np.random.choice(main_array, 3, replace=False, p=p / np.sum(p))
print(y)
```

Comment: You don't need to multiply the boolean array by 1 to turn it to ints. `True` and `False` are already the numbers 1 and 0 respectively. `p = selector > 2; p = p / np.sum(p)` will suffice.